# Классы PHP

Tags: php, классы

С чем связано именование файлов в которых находиться классы, вот таким образом: class.classname.inc.php

Когда можно просто создаться папку classes и там хранить файлы с именем classname.php

Comment: ни с чем, кроме стиля проекта. лучше вообще не заморачиваться на слово класс, а описывать тип класса елсли проект полностью ОО. например

    /controllers/Welcome.php
    /models/Article.php

Comment: Согласен. К тому же такой вариант существенно выигрывает при использовании `namespace` и/или автозагрузчика классов

Comment: "С чем связано именование файлов в которых находиться классы, вот таким образом: "

Вы же погромист! Извольте ставить запятые! (хотя бы, иногда)

И не забывайте про окончания прилагательных!)

Comment: @Deus ))))

Comment: Включите свет - здесь темно :)